# How to calculate cumulative product in SAS?

Tags: sas

I need to create a variable that takes the product of the values of all prior values and including the one in the current obs.

```
data temp;
input time cond_prob;
datalines;    
    1 1
    2 0.2
    3 0.3
    4 0.4
    5 0.6    
;
run;
```

Final data should be:

```
1 1
2 0.2 (1*0.2)
3 0.06 (0.2* 0.3)
4 0.024 (0.06 * 0.4
5 0.0144 (0.024 *0.6)
```

This seems like a simple code but I can't get it to work.  I can do cumulative sums but cumulative product is  not working when using the same logic.

Comment: This belongs on stackoverflow. The answer is a straight-forward application of the "retain" statement in a datastep.

Comment: In the future please include the code you've tried as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the RETAIN functionality.
For the first record I set it to a value of 1 because anything multiplied by 1 will stay the same.

```
data want;
set temp;

retain cum_product 1;

cum_product = cond_prob * cum_product;

run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Reeza.  This is awesome!